# Is it possible to submit a CQL script to a cassandra cluster via the datastax driver?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax

Simply put, I have a cql script I would like to submit to a cluster via the cassandra `Session`, without having to go through cqlsh.

I've looked through their API and I don't see anything to take in a CQL script, or a way to parse a script into `Statement`s that could be fed into a cassandra `Session`.

I suppose I could write something that parses the script myself but surely that must exist already somewhere in the datastax code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't noticed a function to execute a script, but you could write a little loop to read in your script line by line and call:

```
session.execute(cql_line);
```

Where `cql_line` is a string containing a CQL statement.  As long as your script has a complete CQL statement on each line you wouldn't need to do any parsing.

Comment: Is there an update on java driver to execute multiple statements together rather than client looping them?